# Add overlay to UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a `UIImageView` with a `UIImage` (of course).

I want to add this overlay on the image:

hex code: #212530

Opacity: 20%

I've searched everywhere, how can I do that?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, how can I set the opacity using the `TintColor`

Comment: Have a look at Core Image Filter, like [`CIOverlayBlendMode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIOverlayBlendMode)

Comment: @CodeDifferent How can I set the `BackgroundImage` to a specific color?